# how to show left bar and right side bar in open cart homepage

Tags: opencart

I am using  1.5.4 **opencart** for my site. i am wondering from couple of hours but still not getting any accurate solution. please give me solution how i can achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add some modules to the home page to the left and right columns respectively.
in Admin go to Extensions>Modules and add some modules: Layout - Home, Position - Column Left or Column Right.
The default Slideshow module setup won't look right at this point. Just disable it or change it's settings- dimensions/position etc.

[EDIT: in response to comment #1]

I believe you misunderstood my answer:
 in Admin go to Extensions>Modules.

Use Install or Edit buttons on the right side of each module you want to add to your left or right column, for example - "Categories". Then follow what I've written before.

Comment: no this is wrong there is no module layout - home or position column and add module button is also missing
its default new fresh opencart

Answer (score 1):

go to extensions->module->category..
then select home as layout..
hope this works for u..